# Google Script createEvent() function suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Finally I was able to create function that will automatically update event in a calendar. I tested it and it worked perfectly; it will add new event in the calendar, and when user edits it, it will delete previous event and create new event along with new ID.

The next day however, when I tested it again, it doesn't work, I checked all functions in the code.gs, only this function has problem.

```
function updateCalendar(request) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);
var values = range.getDisplayValues(); 
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com');
var numValues = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {    
    if (values[i][0].length > 0) {      
        if (values[i][12] == undefined) {
            var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
            var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];
            //mark as entered, enter ID
            sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue('y');
            sheet.getRange(i+2,12).setValue(newEventId);
        } 
        else if (values[i][12] == 'y') {
            var eventEditId = calendar.getEventSeriesById(values[i][11]);
            eventEditId.deleteEventSeries();
            var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
            var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];;
            //mark as entered, enter ID
            sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue('y');
            sheet.getRange(i+2,12).setValue(newEventId);
        } 
    }
    numValues++;
}
};
```

I also checked the calendar settings and stuffs, and made sure that I was logged into the admin account. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If nothing changed in your code between when it worked and when it didn't, then something changed externally. Maybe it's a permission issue? Or a throttling issue? Otherwise, something in your code changed. Knowing what's not going right, other than it doesn't work now, will help. For instance, is there an exception? This is also why having a minimum reproducible example is important. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some guidance on that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, for some reason I got it working again. the problem was with (values[i][12] == undefined)......I changed it to (values[i][12] == ' '), and it worked again. Im just wondering why it worked last time...maybe something with undefined? Does "undefined" means the value is empty?

Comment: `'' == undefined` should be true in JavaScript. One of the reasons you always always ALWAYS identical-equals - i.e `'' === undefined` will be false - unless you know what you're doing and like lovely issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed "undefined" to simply a null string ' ' , it works again. But again, for some reason i am curious why it worked last time with "undefined" command

Comment: See my last comment for why. You really should fix that. Unless you like torturing yourself like this xD you really should `values[i][12] === '' || values[i][12] === undefined ` instead and stick to it. Otherwise you're gonna face this same problem again when you least expect it.